# How can I add transition to Path in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add transition to a Path in a Shape, looking to add Transition to Path-Shape not adding a Transition to view. How can I do this?

For example we can have a transition for a view like this: `.transition(AnyTransition.opacity)` looking something like that for a Path in Shape.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        MyShape(show: show).stroke()
        Button("update") { show.toggle() }
    }
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    let show: Bool
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            if show {
                // Adding Transition here!
                path.addLines([CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you mean by "path transition" then?

Comment: I updated my question.